# Aws --version command works in jmeter, however other aws commands which needs --profile throws error in jmeter

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter

I am trying to access aws cloudwatch metrics through jmeter for further processing. In order to do this, i am using OS sampler in JMeter,which has command as aws and parameter as my --version. So when i execute this, i get a result regarding my aws cli.

However when i am trying to use `aws cloudwatch --profile test get-metrics` etc, i am getting error in listerner that invalid parameters/commands,though similar commands works with command prompt.
Can some one help me with this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUDMD.png)
My issue is JMeter recognizes aws,however its not able execute any other commabd other than aws --version

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to call [`cmd`](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/CMD_Survival.html) or [`bash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) interpreter depending on your operating system, like:

[image: "/usr/local/bin/aws cloudwatch --profile test get-metrics"]

More information: [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)

Comment: Now i am getting Response code:500
Response message:Exception occurred whilst executing system call: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/bin/bash" (in directory "C:\Users\212674872\Documents\AWS\apache-jmeter-5.3\bin"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
My issue is not running commands,aws --version commands works fine.but it its not recognizing other aws commands which requires --profile.How to make those commands work?

Comment: Every time i run any other command apart from aws --version,it  throws error
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

accessanalyzer                           | acm

Answer (score 0):

The reason that error was being thrown is having all AWS cli params/properties sent on the same line of Command Parameters in OS Process Sampler.
AWS CLI v2 commands from JMeter on Windows (I use 10) need to be split on **multi-line**.
Below is my setup.

[image]

the original command is:

```
$ aws dynamodb list-tables
```

Result:

[image]